# Already indexed error: what does it mean?

Tags: neo4j

I'm writing a quite new application, using an already consolidated DB.
An Index already exists into the DB, for :Identity(uuid), but IMHO, shouldn't be an issue

I received the following error:

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-02 03:32:01 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 74ms

Neo4j::Server::CypherResponse::ResponseError (Already indexed :Identity(uuid).):
  app/models/identity.rb:1:in `'

```
class Identity  < CommonBaseClass 
end 

class CommonBaseClass 
    include Neo4j::ActiveNode
    property :id
    property :created_at, type: DateTime
    property :updated_at, type: DateTime
  # property :uuid 

    property :name
    property :description
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you had a manual index there, drop it. I think neo4j.rb wants to create a constraint instead which conflicts with the manual (potentially not unique) index.

Comment: Couldn't replace it autonomously? There should be any problems in restricting a constraint ....

Comment: Are you using Neo4j.rb 3.0.1? I am almost positive that a feature was added that will look for this and correct it silently, but maybe it only looks for existing constraints.

To fix this manually, just go into the web console and run the query: `DROP INDEX ON : CommonBaseClass(uuid)`.